# Changing the return type of a function returning a Result

Tags: rust, return-value

I have a crate with the function `sys_info::hostname` which returns the hostname. The only problem is that [hostname returns](http://docs.fillzpp.org/sys-info-rs/sys_info/fn.hostname.html) `Result<String, Error>`, but I need another function that must have a return type `Result<(), String>`. How can I call `sys_info::hostname` and return the hostname in a function that doesn't return the same type? Before you ask, the second function's return type cannot be changed due to formatting issues.

Comment: Your question doesn't really give enough information to answer it in a useful way. What do you expect to happen to the `Ok(String)` or the `Err(Error)`? How do you convert between the two representations?

Comment: Sorry, [here[(http://pastebin.com/H2ngtRJF) is the code I'm working with, hopefully that clears up what my problem is?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `try!` macro, which you can't use if the result type is incompatible, use a `match` statement to take apart the return value of `sys_info::hostname` and do what you need to with its parts. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=struct%20Error%3B%0A%0Afn%20thing_returning_result%28succeed%3A%20bool%29%20-%3E%20Result%3CString%2C%20Error%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20succeed%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok%28%22Hello%22.into%28%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err%28Error%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20thing_returning_other_result%28succeed%3A%20bool%29%20-%3E%20Result%3C%28%29%2C%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20thing_returning_result%28succeed%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok%28s%29%20%3D%3E%20Err%28s%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err%28_%29%20%3D%3E%20Err%28%22whoopsies%22.into%28%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20thing_returning_other_result%28false%29%29%3B%0A%7D&version=stable)

```
struct Error;

fn thing_returning_result(succeed: bool) -> Result<String, Error> {
    if succeed {
        Ok("Hello".into())
    } else {
        Err(Error)
    }
}

fn thing_returning_other_result(succeed: bool) -> Result<(), String> {
    match thing_returning_result(succeed) {
        Ok(s) => Err(s),
        Err(_) => Err("whoopsies".into())
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", thing_returning_other_result(false));
}
```

Comment: I apologize for this question; but how do I go about using http://docs.fillzpp.org/sys-info-rs/sys_info/fn.hostname.html ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you've tried that hasn't worked? I can't think of a more helpful answer than "you call the function" right now.

Comment: I'll assume that what you want to do is return early with an error message if `hostname` returns an error, and continue on and do other stuff if it succeeds. [This](http://is.gd/f0i6ni) is an example of doing something like that. Is there any part of it that confuses you?

Comment: That's a good example -- doesn't confuse me. The only part I run into trouble with is the fact that I can't change the second function to 'succeed: bool', it has to be `cmd: &super::ShellCommand`

Comment: The boolean parameter was just so I could easily change the example to simulate `hostname` succeeding or failing. You can take that parameter out and use the real `hostname` function and it'll work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map) and [`map_err`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err):

```
struct Error;

fn inner() -> Result<String, Error> {
    Err(Error)
}

fn outer() -> Result<(), String> {
    inner()
        .map(|ok_val| ())
        .map_err(|err_val| "Something".to_string())
}

fn main() {
    outer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

First try:

```
fn is_url(val: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    match Url::parse(val) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(_) => Err(format!("The URL '{}' is an invalid URL.", val)),
    }
}
```

More concise:

```
fn is_url(val: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    Url::parse(val).map_err(|_| format!("The URL '{}' is an invalid URL.", val))?;
    Ok(())
}
```